# Does Apple run a full EMV kernel on the iPhone?

Tags: apple-pay

I was wondering whether Apple Pay uses an EMV kernel. If so is there more information available like the implementation and who supplies it?

Comment: This is not a broad question. It's a very specific question. Essentially, devices with Apple Pay have a standard NFC Secure Element, which is used exclusively for handing the EMV contactless transactions. This can be contrasted with Google's approach, which is host card emulation.  (I was starting to write an answer for this which could fit in a few paragraphs when this was closed.)

Comment: The edit actually made it even broader. Is the question about "how does Apple Pay work", is it about "is the EMV kernel written in Java", is it about "Does Apple Pay need to be updated for every payment scheme and if yes, how" or about something completely different? Also it's not really clear which actual problem it solves and whether there has been any research on this by the OP already.

Comment: The question is about the EMV kernel of Apple Pay only. OP has done a limited amount of research but none of the articles about Apple Pay the found mentioned anything about an EMV kernel.